# SQL Server - Query to get server's IP address with Availability Group Listener

Tags: sql-server

There is another question like this and the most common answer is to use CONNECTIONPROPERTY( 'local_net_address' ).  The Microsoft documentation says this returns the "targetted" address.  So when I connect using an AG listener, local_net_address returns the AG listener IP no matter which SQL Server I am really connected to.  So how to get the SQL Server IP address when using an AG listener?

This will be running in a secure environment and xp_cmdshell is not an option.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> the SQL Server IP address when using an AG listener

A server doesn't have just one IP address.  For instance the AG Listener IP you use to connect is an additional IP address for the server.  It's typically as good as any *other* IP address the server might have.

In the most common configuration, SQL Server has *absolutely no* knowledge about the server's IPs.  SQL Server simply listens on port 1433 *all* IPs.

You can query the server name and domain, and construct a DNS lookup to find an IP associated with that server name:

```
select  DEFAULT_DOMAIN() domain, serverproperty('ComputerNamePhysicalNetBIOS') serverName
```

Comment: In my case the hostname is good.  I made the bad assumption the IP would be easier.  I tested this and it does return the other server name after a fail over.